# Error : 'vectorName' does not name a type

Tags: c++, vector

I set up a vector instead of an array because I needed to find the size of the array and I could not figure how to do that. When I set up the vector I wrote std::vector prime; and the next line is prime.push_back(2) and the error says 'prime' does not name a type. Here's my code:

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
unsigned int c = 0;
std::vector<int> prime;
prime.push_back(2);
int main()
{

    for (int i = 3; i < 10; i = i + 2)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < prime.size(); j++)
        {
            if (i % prime[j] != 0)
            {
                c = c + 1;
            }
        }
        if (c == prime.size())
        {
            prime.push_back(i);
            c = 0;
            cout << i << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've been trying to solve the problem but to no avail. I'm a beginner in c++(I've been coding in it for two days) and I don't really know the basics.

Comment: You need to put `prime.push_back(2);` inside `main`.  You can't "run" arbitrary code outside a function.  You can only declare/define things in namespace scope.

Comment: Or initialize it with `std::vector<int> prime({2});`.